# Se pueden agregar datos al Map<>Hashmap estando en otra activity diferente? (Android Studio/Firebase database)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, map, hashmap

He tratado de que la parte de "Image" vaya dentro de cada "User", sin embargo no he tenido exito.

[image: S]

Este es el codigo que usé

> //Esto era solo para subir la imagen

```
            final StorageReference Imagename = mstorage.child("image" + ImageData.getLastPathSegment());

            Imagename.putFile(ImageData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Imagename.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
```

*Desde aquí es el código para subir el archivo al Database*
                  @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

```
                            DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Image");
                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("imageurl", String.valueOf(uri));

                            imagestore.setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Pantallaprincipal.this,"Exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

Todo funciona a la perfección, sin embargo quisiera que la imagen esté dentro de cada usuario para usarla como foto de perfil.

Comment: hola! Aprovecho el post para consultar si conocen un buen post acerca de la clase map hashmap. Gracias

Comment: Es que la referencia que estás creando no apunta a `User`, prueba así: **`DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User/Image");`**

Comment: Ahora si está dentro de usuarios ; sin embargo yo quisiera que sea una poto por cada usuario, y con ese código lo deja fuera del Hashmap de cada uno de los usuarios y por cada foto que se sube, se elimina la antes seleccionada en el database

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres. Muestra cómo queda ahora y explica con una estructura de árbol el resultado esperado. Tampoco entiendo por qué usas un `HashMap` ¿?  ¿Quieres guardar varias cosas relativas a la imagen o es solamente la url de la misma?

Comment: He creado un nuevo post, espero que me puedas ayudar, en todo caso, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que necesitas, tenes que modificar la referencia.

Si el usuario fue creado por un login con Firebase, deberias usar `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();` para obtener esa ID alfanumerica que se encuentra en `User`, esa es la id del usuario logueado en ese momento.

```
 DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Image");
```

Si no logueaste al usuario , deberias escribir en el segundo child de la referencia el Uid del usuario donde queres guardar la imagen.

Si no queres guardar un nodo `Image` con `imageUrl` adentro del usuario, solo guardala adentro del usuario como un atributo mas que seria `imageUrl`

```
DatabaseReference imagestore = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```